# AngularJS : ng-controller on directive does not work on transcluded elements within directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6CXWN/) is my script:

```
angular.module('MyApp',[])
.directive('mySalutation',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:true,
        replace:true,
        transclude:true,
        template:'<div>Hello<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
        link:function($scope,$element,$attrs){
        }
    };
})
.controller('SalutationController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.target = "StackOverflow";
}])
```

and the html:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <my-salutation ng-controller="SalutationController">
        <strong>{{target}}</strong>        
    </my-salutation>
</body>
```

The problem is , when `SalutationController` is applied on `my-salutation` directive, `$scope.target` *is not visible* for transcluded element.But if I put `ng-controller` on `<body>` or on `<strong>` element, it works. As [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) says, `ng-controller` creates new scope.

- Who can explain, how that scope and the scope of the directive are interfering with each other in this case?
- How can I put controller on directive? Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this necessary? Directives can take a `controller` parameter in the object, in addition to the `link` parameter.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung Yes, you can add controller option on directive, but in that case you will have same controller for all directive instances. What if I do not want any controller for my directive, or I need another controller?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) The problem is `ng-transclude`'s scope is the **sibling** scope of your directive. When you put the `ng-controller` to a parent element, the scope created by `ng-controller` is parent scope of both your directive and `ng-transclude`. Due to scope inheritance, the transcluded element is able to bind the `{{target}}` correctly.

2) You could do that using custom transclusion to bind the scope yourself

```
.directive('mySalutation',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:true,
        replace:true,
        transclude:true,
        template:'<div>Hello<div class="transclude"></div></div>',
        compile: function (element, attr, linker) {
            return function (scope, element, attr) {
                linker(scope, function(clone){
                       element.find(".transclude").append(clone); // add to DOM
                });

            };
        }
    };
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uLWsX/)

Or using the transclude function in the link function:

```
.directive('mySalutation',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:true,
        replace:true,
        transclude:true,
        template:'<div>Hello<div class="transclude"></div></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr,controller, linker) {
           linker(scope, function(clone){
                  element.find(".transclude").append(clone); // add to DOM
           });
        }
    };
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uLWsX/1/)

Comment: [Doc states](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile): "Note: The transclude function that is passed to the compile function is deprecated, as it e.g. does not know about the right outer scope. Please use the transclude function that is passed to the link function instead.". This is new in Angular 1.2, as per [this post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2561-Changes-In-Transclude-Function-Availability-In-AngularJS-1-2.htm).

Comment: @kamituel: Thanks, I did not know it has changed. I have updated the answer (The idea is the same)

Comment: If I understood your first point correctly, that means if I'll not create new scope for directive,that is `scope` is set to `false`, then  the code should work. Why it does not work in that case?

Comment: @Engineer: When I debugged. I noticed that there is no difference with `true`, `false`. In both cases, the directive scope is the controller scope (same $id). I think angular does not create a scope if there is already one even if `scope:true`

Comment: Note that find() only supports tag names, so you may need to do angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.classname')).append(clone). Also, if you are using an isolated scope, you may need to do linker(scope.$parent, ...)

Comment: @devdigital: that would not be a problem if we include jQuery on the page.

Answer (score 2):

To have the same scope for the directive, and the controller, you can invoke the transcludeFn manually:

```
angular.module('MyApp',[])
.directive('mySalutation',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:true,
        replace:true,
        transclude:true,
        template:'<div>Hello<div class="trans"></div></div>',
        link:function(scope, tElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn){
                console.log(scope.$id);
                transcludeFn(scope, function cloneConnectFn(cElement) {
                    tElement.after(cElement);
                }); 
        }
    };
})
.controller('SalutationController',['$scope',function($scope){
    console.log($scope.$id);
    $scope.target = "StackOverflow";
}]);
```

[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/GvIhA444jgRClsPoA6zO?p=preview)

You can see that '003' is logged out every time, and your code works as expected with this minor adjustment.